# How do I loop over each hh:00 whithin a time period in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, for-loop, timestamp

I let's say I have the following time period:

```
long start = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-01-01 00:00:00").getTime();
long end = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-02-01 00:00:00").getTime();
```

I want to loop through this time period and do something for each hh:00, which means:

```
"2021-01-01 00:00:00"
"2021-01-01 01:00:00"
"2021-01-01 02:00:00"
"2021-01-01 03:00:00"
"2021-01-01 04:00:00"
etc.
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**A sample solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Parse the start and end Date-Time strings into `LocalDateTime` and iterate from the start to end checking the loop termination condition using [`LocalDateTime#isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strStartDateTime = "2021-01-01 00:00:00";
        String strEndDateTime = "2021-01-01 10:00:00";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDateTime ldtStart = LocalDateTime.parse(strStartDateTime, dtf);
        LocalDateTime ldtEnd = LocalDateTime.parse(strEndDateTime, dtf);

        for (LocalDateTime ldt = ldtStart; !ldt.isAfter(ldtEnd); ldt = ldt.plusHours(1)) {
            // System.out.println(ldt);

            // Formatted
            System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));

            // ...Your logic
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00
2021-01-01 01:00:00
2021-01-01 02:00:00
2021-01-01 03:00:00
2021-01-01 04:00:00
2021-01-01 05:00:00
2021-01-01 06:00:00
2021-01-01 07:00:00
2021-01-01 08:00:00
2021-01-01 09:00:00
2021-01-01 10:00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sJCKSZ)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use a ScheduledExecutorService:

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to execute something every hour, I'm trying to get every hour whithin the given period...

Comment: Cast time to LocalDateTime and use LocalDateTime.plusHours(long hours)

Answer (score 0):

In modern SDKs (java 8 and above) `java.sql.Timestamp` should be used only in the database layer. All other layers, should use modern `java.time.Instant`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Duration d = Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS);

    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant lastFourHours = now.minus(4, ChronoUnit.HOURS);

    while (lastFourHours.isBefore(now)) {
        // do something each hour

        lastFourHours = lastFourHours.plus(d);
    }
}
```

*PS: `Instant` is what it says it is...an instant. That means it has no timezone information. This also means it deals in UTC.*